# How to fix a broken error message in MacVim?

Tags: vim, macvim

I get a broken error message when using the command `:!ruby %`.

```
puts 'Hello world'
lfd
```

What I get:

```
Hello world
[1mTraceback[m (most recent call last):
Documents/Ruby/stack.rb:2:in `<main>': [1mundefined local variable
or method `lfd' for main:Object ([1;4mNameError[m[1m)[m

shell returned 1
```

What I want to get (So it works through the terminal):

```
Hello world
Traceback (most recent call last):
stack.rb:2:in `<main>': undefined local variable
or method `lfd' for main:Object (NameError)
```

I know what Ruby doesn't understand what `lfd` is. I mean, some words are displayed incorrectly here. I highlighted the differences in red and green in the screenshots.

What I get:
[image: result]

> I use MacVim 8.2

What I want to get (Terminal):
[image: rusult2]

Comment: Please put all your output into the question. Linking to an image does not help others if the file does nto exist anymore.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the problem is not in vim. Ruby doesn't understand what `lfd` is. And `puts 'Hello world'` came true.
[image]

Comment: Yes, I know about it, the error was made on purpose. I updated the question to make it more clear.

Answer (score 0):

Those are ANSI escape sequences, generally used to stylize output.

In the MacVim GUI, `:!<external program>` is executed in a "dumb shell" that doesn't support ANSI escape sequences. This means that:

- all attempts to stylize text in this environment are doomed to fail,
- either the program has a switch to disable color or it knows when to do it.

That said, `$ ruby filename` is not supposed to use styling in its output to begin with so you should investigate why it does that for you first.